# Alternative to Microsoft Flow

Tags: database, automation

Been trying Microsoft Power Automate (Flow) for some time now and i'm tired of having to do workarounds for the simplest task due to poor support and connectors.

I'm automating database related tasks (no desktop automation or RPA), and currently i'm facing these issues (to mention a few):

- Cannot do manual MSSQL, Mysql or Postgresql queries (must create SPs for everything)
- Cannot query MySQL with datetime-filter (filter input requires timezone, database has no and it fails)
- Must create ids manually in Postgres and Mysql even if the column in auto increment
- On prem gateway has extremely limited support for connectors
- Big flows are cumbersome to work with due to horrible GUI

Are there any good alternatives?